# React native 0.45.1 Showing blank screen on phone and emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've used the react-native init tool to create a react native project. But I've tried to run it on my emulator and my phone and after fetching the JS bundle, it just shows a blank white screen. Remote debugger hangs on 'Connecting to remote debugger'. I've tried to run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 and setting my remote debugging server address in the dev settings but none of that worked.

What is weird is that this all works fine with react 15.*.* and react-native 0.42.*. NPM isn't complaining. My Phone is a Google Pixel and I'm running several emulators. Nexus 5, 6 and Pixel none of em work

Comment: Turns out you need to completely close the application and reopen it. Not sure if this is a os specific thing or just a react native version thing but it works now.

Comment: RN 0.46.4 over here... same issue. Only when remote debugging is enabled and when reloading the app during the same debug session.
Even closing/opening the app every time gets annoying after a while